# Recursive expression for Inorder Traversal?

Tags: c++, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

```
void inorder(Node *root){
if(root!=NULL){
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->key<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);    
}
```

I want to know how is inorder traversal of binary tree is O(n) mathematically?
Shouldn't it be T(N) = 2*T(n-1) + const. ?

Comment: `2*O(n-1) + const` is  `O(n)`

Comment: Recursive function doesn't work like this. if the function would beT(n) = T(n-1) then the time complexity would be O(n). But here T(N) = 2*T(n-1) + const. which implies time complexity to be O(2^n).